# Find the book with the most upvotes(like=1) per author

Tags: mysql, sql

### Given these tables below

#### Authors Table

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Ron |
| 2 | John |

#### Books Table

| ID | Title | author_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Book1 | 1 |
| 2 | Book2 | 1 |
| 3 | Book3 | 2 |

#### Votes Table

| ID | book_id | Vote(like = 1, dislike = 0) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 0 |

### query i composed

```
SELECT
      name,
      b.title,
      MAX(upvote)
FROM
     (SELECT
             COUNT(IF(v.vote = 1, v.vote, NULL)) AS upvote,
             b.id AS book_id,
             b.author_id AS author_id
      FROM
           books b
           LEFT JOIN votes v ON b.id = v.book_id
      GROUP BY b.author_id, b.id
     )AS X
    LEFT JOIN books b ON x.book_id = b.id
     INNER JOIN authors a ON x.author_id = a.id
GROUP BY a.id
```

Problem: Find the book with the most upvotes(like=1) per author.

im stuck on this problem for 2 hours or so now, i still couldnt get the title of the MAX(vote). Based on the table above, in the main SELECT clause, it must return Book1 but instead I get Book2.
Now how will I get the title of the MAX(vote)? I still couldn't figure out how to solve this one.

Answer (score 0):

I have simulated your tables and result is below.
I think you think very complex about this issue.
If this is not what you are looking for please share a sample table what you want to see as a result so I will try to help you.

EDIT: Updated table and SQL query according to your new needs.

```
+----+-------+-----------+------+----------+------------+
| id | title | author_id | name | vote_sum | vote_count |
+----+-------+-----------+------+----------+------------+
|  1 | Book1 |     1     |  Ron |     2    |      2     |
+----+-------+-----------+------+----------+------------+
|  2 | Book2 |     1     |  Ron |     0    |      1     |
+----+-------+-----------+------+----------+------------+
|  3 | Book3 |     2     | John |   NULL   |      0     |
+----+-------+-----------+------+----------+------------+
```

```sql
SELECT 
    books.id,
    books.title,
    books.author_id,
    authors.name,
    SUM(votes.vote) as vote_sum,
    COUNT(votes.vote) as vote_count
FROM books
LEFT JOIN authors ON books.author_id = authors.id
LEFT JOIN votes ON books.id = votes.book_id
GROUP BY books.title, authors.id
ORDER BY vote_sum DESC
```

Comment: Your simulated table is right. I was given a hint, and this was his suggestion, " You should get the count of upvotes grouped by author and book. then get the maximum upvotes for the author. Then use that maximum upvote per author as filter for the number of book upvotes"

Comment: I have updated it check it out. If you can share a table like me I can help you better. What you want is grouping more than one column and two aggregate functions. These are possible I have many queries working very complex but I need more data to write that kind of a query. Otherwise we can't be sure if query is working properly or not. So provide more data and share final table of your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest aproach is to join and count first and then look at the authors' maximum upvotes in this intermediate result with an analytic function:

```
select name, title, upvotes
from
(
  select
    a.name,
    b.title,
    count(*) as upvotes,
    max(count(*)) over (partition by a.id) as max_upvotes_for_author
  from authors a
  join books b on b.author_id = a.id
  join votes v on v.book_id = b.id and v.vote = 1
  group by b.id
) counted
where upvotes = max_upvotes_for_author
order by name;
```

This is standard SQL. `MAX OVER` is featured since MySQL 8.

---

Your own query is invalid. In your main query you group by author, but select a book title. As an author can have written many books, you would have to tell the DBMS *which* book to select.

As is, the DBMS should raise an error. If it doesn't, then you are not working in `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode. Unfortunately, MySQL allows a cheat mode instead and silently applies `ANY_VALUE` to all columns that are not dependent on the `GROUP BY` clause then. What is happening in your query hence is that you involuntarily select `ANY_VALUE(b.title)` and the DBMS just picks a book title per author arbitrarily.

Make sure to `SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY';` in MySQL in order to avoid writing invalid queries.